# Pulling string from textarea (MVC)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I made a textarea where I want people to be able to enter a comment. I then have a method in a controller that is supposed to use that string.

How do I pull the information from the textarea into the method?

Comment: How do you reach that method? When handling a POST request?

Comment: MVC does not work the same as webforms, where you can pull the value out of the textarea  from the codebehind. Marios answer below is how you need to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how your View or Action method looks like, but give your TextArea a name, like `comment`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController")) {
    @Html.TextArea("comment")

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

And then make sure you have a parameter in your action with the same name:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(string comment)
{
    // Do something with the comment
}
```

When you post, the default model binders will take care of putting the text from your TextArea into the `comment` parameter.